# Can anyone identify this Tandem bike I restored from a junk yard?

Tags: identify-this-bike, tandems, vintage

[image: unidentifiedtandem]

This is a bike that I rescued from an abandoned junk yard in central California. It was terribly rusted, and I think I am crazy for spending the amount of time and money I did to restore it. I often wish that I would have just walked right on by it! It had remnants of rubbery decals on it, but they were far unreadable. The gear changer says "FALCON" on it. Unfortunately that is the only thing with a name on the bike. Does anybody know what this bike is? Or perhaps how old it may be?

Comment: I would say it dates from the 70s.  Schwinn or something like Western Auto would be a good guess, maybe Murray.  Unfortunately not a real high-quality bike, but you sure cleaned it up nice.  (I vaguely remember Falcon derailers, but I don't remember what bikes they were on.)

Comment: See the second picture on this page -- not identical but pretty close: http://vanscyoc.net/blog/plugin/tag/original

Comment: If it's Columbia they didn't produce that frame style until 1979:http://www.vintagecolumbiabikes.com/id113.html

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar frame on a tandem from Craigslist several years ago. That was a Schwinn.
The frame is terribly flexible, you can't put an adult on the rear seat.